# Excel Macro Automatic copy paste when opening the file

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

We have 2 different files with basic vlookup infos:

```
Source file is: JP2-CSV CRAWLER
Destination file is: JP2-CATEGORIES
```

We are trying to copy one full column from the Source file to the first column of the destination file automatically ( It should work when opening it or using it)

That's our code:

```
Sub Copysubcat()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDestination As Workbook

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open( _
    Filename:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\crawler file\JP2-CSV CRAWLER.xlsx")

Set wbDestination = Workbooks("C:\Users\user\Desktop\crawler file\JP2-CATEGORIES.xlsx")

wbSource.Sheets("CSV Crawler").Range("P2:P10000").Copy

wbDestination.Sheets("Cats & Subcats").Range("A2:A10000").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

We are having an error "Subscript out of range"

Anybody could help on that?

Comment: it could help if you tell us at which line are you getting this error

Comment: try `wbDestination.Sheets("Cats & Subcats").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: This is the line: Set wbDestination = Workbooks("C:\Users\user\Desktop\crawler file\JP2-CATEGORIES.xlsx")

Comment: @DareJc if the workbook is already open, use `Set wbDestination = Workbooks("JP2-CATEGORIES.xlsx")` , if not, and you need to open it first, then use `Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\crawler file\JP2-CATEGORIES.xlsx")` (not in the middle, like you have it).

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks` isn't a method, so it cannot take any parameters. This is class, which represents workbooks, which contains methods to handle them. One of them is `Open` which you will need in this case. So you'll need to switch this:

```
Set wbDestination = Workbooks("C:\Users\user\Desktop\crawler file\JP2-CATEGORIES.xlsx")
```

to this:

```
Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\crawler file\JP2-CATEGORIES.xlsx")
```

Also, there is an event such as opening the workbook, you can place your corrected code there, so the macro would run every time this event is raised (i.e. on every opening). If you are using standard VBA development environment in Excel, click on `This_workbook` on right side (in tree view), you will have to dropdown lists at the top, in the one on the left choose `Workbook`, in the other one select `Open` (this is list of events, that is raised by `Workbook`). Then, inside generated method place youre code :)

[image]

Comment: nice explanation, try also adding the correct syntax for each scenario

Comment: Thanks Michal, I Can't find the event, do you have any screenshot available.

Comment: I attached a picture. I have polish language set on my system, so don't worry about the name. Pick the one with same icon :)

Comment: Thanks Michal, Ok i managed to do it but i a have a few more questiosn:

 It opens 2 files, one older version with the macro code in it but the datas are not uploaded and an uploaded one that does not retain the macro code. Is there anyway to just update the file and save it (replace it) with the new one retaining the code?

Comment: You can write more code, which will close opened workbook, delete it and rename current one. Everything can be done, requires just some google skills :) Also, if your question is answered, please accept the answer, so in the future people will know what was the (accepted) solution :)